# Is there a way to add arithmetic operator inside a function in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a express app with a booking form using ejs and adding functionality inside it. it's used as a payment.

I have a `select tag` and stored it's `selected text` inside of a variable. Console logging it gives the value but using it in the actual code gives an error that says it's undefined.

What I need is to take the value of the selected input, for example `2` and multiply it to the tour.price amount, for example `34000` so the total would be `68000` and put inside the addCommas() `Amount: $  <%= addCommas(34000 * 2) %>` `//the total should be 68000 then the function addCommas() which would make it 68,000`.

I tried using Scriptlet' tag of ejs and put this code on top of the file

```
<%let selectedText = document.querySelector("#numOfPersons")%>
<%let valueOfSelected = selectedText.options[selectedText.selectedIndex].value %>    
<form>
     <div>
        <label for="numOfPersons">Number of Persons</label>
        <select id="numOfPersons">
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
        </select>
      </div>

     Amount: $  <%= addCommas(tour.price * valueOfSelected) %> //addCommas() is a function that takes a number and adds comma every three numbers, ex: 100000 will become 100,000.
// tour.price is the total amount of the product. It's a Number. it's current value is 34000
</form>
```

It says that valueOfSelected is not defined.
my second attempt is adding 
`<%let selectedText = document.querySelector("#numOfPersons")%>`
`<%let valueOfSelected = selectedText.options[selectedText.selectedIndex].value %>`  below the form tag but it also says not defined.

Then I tried adding script tag below the file 
`<script>
let selectedText = document.querySelector("#numOfPersons");
let valueOfSelected = 
selectedText.options[selectedText.selectedIndex].value;
</script>`

and then for my final attempt, I do this. 

  `let totalAmount = tour.price * Number(valueOfSelected);
  document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "Amount: $  <%= addCommas(totalAmount) %>"`

All come out as not defined

The expected result should output a total price of $68,000 when `<%= addCommas(tour.price * valueOfSelected) %>` is called

P.S. For some reason, I cannot create another code block using 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever DOM operations like getting selected text cannot be written directly in ejs file. You have to do that inside the script tag(i.e. using js) as in your second approach.

Inside the script try getting values after the document is loaded:

```
<script>
function addCommas() { // implement the function here }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // get values here like the `valueOfSelected`
  var tourPrice = "<%= tour.price %>";

  var valueWithCommasAdded = addCommas(tourPrice * valueOfSelected);
  var content = document.createTextNode("Amount: " + valueWithCommasAdded);

  // Finally append to the form
  document.forms[0].appendChild(content);

});
</script>
```

You have to do this way because you have to wait for the document to load fully. The ejs will have loaded already before you can get value from the DOM. You have to do the calculation dynamically with javascript and place in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and it works until ` var valueWithCommasAdded` by doing `console.log(valueWithCommasAdded)` but the appending part gives an error in the console. ` Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>` where does `document.forms[0]` takes it?
I also tried this instead yours by putting a <p> tag inside the form with id of #total, `document.getElementById('#total').innerHTML(valueWithCommasAdded);` . my attempt also failed

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Turns out you need to add a text node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is working now. But when I select another option inside the select tag, It's not updating. I will find a solution on my own on this one. Thank you again!